# OutOfMemoryError while break zip file into two parts

Tags: glassfish-3, fileinputstream, fileoutputstream, java-6

My application breaks .zip file into two parts. It works fine when file size is under 100MB. If file size is more than 100MB it gives

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
    at java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:198)
```

I'm using glassfishV3 and JDK6

-Xms512m  -Xmx512m is not enough

```
then I have set 
<jvm-options>-Xms1024m</jvm-options>
<jvm-options>-Xmx1024m</jvm-options>
```

but then it gives

```
"Error occurred during initialization of VM Could not reserve enough space for object heap Could not create the Java virtual machine."

public void create() {
    byte[] bFile = takeByteArr("file1.zip");
    byte[] bPart1 = Arrays.copyOfRange(bFile, 0, 100000);
    byte[] bPart2 = Arrays.copyOfRange(bFile, 100000, bFile.length);
    createFile(bPart1, "part1.zip");
    createFile(bPart2, "part2.zip");
}

void createFile(byte[] bFile, String path) {
    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(path);
        fos.write(bFile);
        fos.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println("FileNotFoundException : " + ex);
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        System.out.println("IOException : " + ioe);
    }
}

byte[] takeByteArr(String filePath) {
    File file = new File(filePath);
    byte[] bFile = new byte[(int) file.length()];
    try {
        FileInputStream  fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        fileInputStream.read(bFile);
        fileInputStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return bFile;
}
```

Comment: How much RAM is there on your computer? And how many free RAM is there when you get this message? Do you have a 32 or 64 bits system and JDK. When I have this message I try to close as many programs as possible and start again, most of the time it's enough.

Comment: Does it really have to be done in Java? Maybe an OS command can be called from Java to split the file...

Comment: *Why* are you doing this? The parts make no sense without all the other parts. It seems futile. In any case it certainly isn't going to work if you just copy the first 100000 bytes into another piece of memory and then assume that the rest is going to fit into memory too, as well as the original file. Files should be processed a line or a record or a buffer at a time.

Comment: @StephaneM -  My computer RAM is 4GB and 1.5GB is available. It's running on 64bit windows 7 OS and JDK 64bit.

Comment: @BorisPavlovic - yes I have to do it in java. I'm developing this application in windows 7. But I have to deploy it in centOs. So I think use Os command will not help to solve this problem.

Comment: @chamikaWKK the JVM tries to allocate 1Gb contiguous memory, as you only have 1.5Gb out of 4Gb free, the odds that there is so much contiguous free memory are very low. Try to close as many program as possible to free memory and start again, just to check you can get it started at least once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already suggested in a comment large files are not read in one part but into a smaller buffer. The buffer is then processed, in your case this would be saving the part file to disk, and reused in a loop which reads the file chunk by chunk. This method has the advantage that you only need as much memory as the size of your buffer is.

The FileInputStream class has a method named [read(byte[] b, int off, int len)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read(byte[],%20int,%20int)) which reads **len** number of bytes starting at offset **off** in byte array **b** from the InputStream. The method returns an int representing the number of bytes read during the method call and **-1** if nothing could be read.

Example:

```
    byte[] b = new byte[1024];
    int read = inputStream.read(b, 0, 1024);
```

Now you have a byte array **b** which is 1024 bytes large and contains **read** bytes of content.

You can loop through your file, but you have to pay attention to the last part. The byte array buffer will also have the size 100000 but I guess you don't want to create the last part with that size. Therefore you have to recreate the buffer with number of bytes which are really the last part of the content.

Your code could look like this:

```
public void create() throws IOException {
    FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File("file1.zip"));

    byte[] b = new byte[100000];
    int read;
    int counter = 0;
    while ((read = in.read(b, 0, 100000)) != -1) {
        if(read != 100000) { // <- the last part
            b = Arrays.copyOfRange(b, 0, read);
        }
        createFile(b, "part" + counter++ + ".zip");
        b = new byte[100000];
    }  
}
```